Round Robin Ping Pong Tournament
There are $n$ players in a round-robin ping-pong tournament (i.e. every two persons will play exactly one game). After some matches have been played, it is known that the total number of matches that have been played among any $n − 2$ people is equal to $3^k$ (where $k$ is a fixed integer). Find the sum of all possible values of $n$ (PUMAC 2008).
I'm confused by the official solution here: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/570450471d07c094a39efaed/t/58b08fc637c581bd4b6cbca0/1487966151033/PUMaC2009_CombinatoricsASol.pdf
As usual, let players be vertices and games be edges.
My idea was to find two ways to count the total number of edges. You could just do $\binom{n}{n-2} 3^k$, but this overcounts the number of edges by a fixed factor. To get this factor I considered the number of times an edge would be counted in the product above. Note that an edge is only counted in the $3^k$ when the $2$ non-included people are disjoint from the edge (what I mean by this is that if the edge is $u-v$, then the two non-included people, $u$ and $v$ must be 4 distinct vertices in the graph.
That means that the number of times I count an edge must be $\binom{n-2}{2}$ (since there are $n-2$ people other than $u$ and $v$ and when I exclude them the edge is counted in the $3^k$). Hence, the number of edges in the graph must be
$$\frac{\binom{n}{n-2}3^k}{\binom{n-2}{2}}.$$
However, the official solution somehow is getting that the number of edges is $$\frac{\binom{n}{n-2}3^k}{\binom{n}{n-4}}.$$
How are they getting this, and what is wrong with my reasoning?

I agree with you.
Let's consider the case where $n=5$ and $k=1$ so

it is known that the total number of matches that have been played among any $n−2(=3)$ people is equal to $3^k(=3)$

Since among $3$ people, up to ${3 \choose 2}=3$ matches can be played, clearly in this example all matches have been played.  The total number of matches is then ${5 \choose 2}=10$ which is $\frac{\binom{5}{5-2}3^k}{\binom{5-2}{2}}$ but not $\frac{\binom{5}{5-2}3^k}{\binom{5}{5-4}}=6$.
Instead if you took $n=4$ and $k=0$, then again all ${4 \choose 2}=6$ matches would be played which is both $\frac{\binom{4}{4-2}3^k}{\binom{4-2}{2}}$ and $\frac{\binom{4}{4-2}3^k}{\binom{4}{4-4}}$.  I suspect an error in the described solution, which may have been partially checked, not picked up  at the time as it gave $5+4=9$ as the sum of all possible values of $n$ and so nobody queried it.

yeah, that makes sense, although I guess the final problem becomes equivalent to asking what values of $n$ there are such that $\frac{n(n-1)}{(n-2)(n-3)}\cdot 3^k$ is an integer for some value of $k$ with $3^k \le \binom{n-2}{2}$, which is a bit more messy to deal with.

@redLotus31415: Is it though? $n(n-1)$ and $(n-2)(n-3)$ have no common prime divisors except $2$ and possibly $3$. This means that the odd one of $n-2$ and $n-3$ has to be a power of $3$, and unless it is $1$, the other one has to be a power of $2$. This does not leave a lot of options, and I think they can probably be easily limited further.

Yeah I think that also works. My idea was that since $n-2$ and $n-3$ are relatively prime, we can consider the expression $n(n-1)3^k$ modulo $n-2$ and $n-3$. This basically gives that $n-2$ has to divide $2\cdot 3^k$ from which you get that $n = 2+3^j$ or $n=2+2\cdot 3^j$ for some $j\le k$. I think you can continue from here and find what $j$ has to be.

You are correct.
The error they made is that for fixed edge $\{u,v\}$ they forgot to exclude $u,v$ in $\binom{n}{n-4}$ ie. it should instead be $\binom{n-2}{n-4}$ which is same as your answer $\binom{n-2}{2}$
